# How can I figure out the function/programming behind the toggle navigation in the Dashgum Bootstrap Theme?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I'm making a system using the [Dashgum Free Bootstrap theme](http://www.blacktie.co/demo/dashgumfree/).

I have it locally but I can't find any programming behind the toggle navigation function, and I need to take a look at it. I'd guess javascript but there's no id related to the element, and even when you delete all attributes, as long as you don't delete the div and there's something inside it (like something written ) it still works.

What kind of sorcery is this? I need to see the code behind scenes!

You can check the code by inspecting the navigation element in the link above. I pasted my own here too, but I don't think it helps, does it? I can't share the system I'm making :(

```html
<div class="sidebar-toggle-box col-lg-2 z-padding">
    <div class="fa fa-bars tooltips " data-placement="right" data-original-title="Encolher/Expandir Menu"></div>
    <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>eCategory</b></a>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: the behaviors are probably defined in bootstrap.js, or a custom js file, which looks for existing markup on the page and makes it do stuff. this style of UI programming is called "declarative", and you're not supposed to worry about the actual code that executes the instructions your provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to inspect the element with Google Chrome. Press F12 then click on the magnifier, position on the element. On the side menu you are going to find Event Listeners, it means all events attached to that element.

[image: inspect]

You might be able to find the function that runs on click this way.

You can also look in the code for code selecting the element (i.e. ".sidebar-toggle-box").

Comment: Thanks! I found the code and were able to do the changes I needed.